# relationship between minimization of quadratic form in $\mathbb R^2$ and second eigenvalue/eignvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

I have come across the following statement in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0031320394001256

The statement (in the right middle of Page 785) is (essentially) the following:

The vector $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R^2}$ minimizing $\boldsymbol{x}^\top\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}$, where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a symmetric positive definite two-dimensional matrix is the same as the eigenvector corresponding to the smaller eigenvalue of $\boldsymbol{A}$.

I understand that the eigenvector corresponding to the larger eigenvalue maximizes the quadratic form. The eigenvector corresponding to the second (smallest in this case) eigenvalue, I thought, was the maximizer of the quadratic form that was also orthogonal to the eigenvector corresponding to the first eigenvalue. Is this also the minimizer? I am looking for a formal proof/explanation.

Comment: Both are true. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are only two eigenvalues so the second largest one is also the smallest one. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ you'd need to distinguish them and the correct generalization is to consider the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, the question is why should the second (or the smallest) eigenvalue minimize the quadratic form?

Comment: Diagonalize the quadratic form and you should see it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I do not see how diagonalizing the quadratic form shows that the maximization problem becomes a minimization problem. Can you please provide me with a solution that I can then accept as the correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be very distracted by the $\mathbb{R}^2$ so let's generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Write a unit vector $x = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i$ as a sum of orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$, so that $\| x \|^2 = \sum c_i^2$. We assume that the eigenvalues have been sorted such that $\lambda_1 \ge \dots \ge \lambda_n$. Now write

$$\langle x, Ax \rangle = \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i, \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \lambda_i v_i \right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i c_i^2.$$

Now the minimization problem is: what unit vector $x$ (you need this condition or else the minimum is just given by $x = 0$) minimizes this sum? Equivalently, we want to minimize $\sum \lambda_i c_i^2$ given the constraint $\sum c_i^2 = 1$. This is a very easy Lagrange multiplier calculation and the answer is that we should take $c_n^2 = 1$ and all other $c_i^2 = 0$, with minimum value $\lambda_n$, the smallest eigenvalue.

When $n = 2$ this smallest eigenvalue is $\lambda_2$ which also happens to be the second largest eigenvalue and hence which also solves a maximization problem.

It's not that "the maximization problem becomes a minimization problem," it's that there are two problems, a maximization problem and a minimization problem, and $\lambda_2$ happens to be the answer to both of them, because it happens to be both the smallest and the second largest eigenvalue in this case. But the distinction becomes clear for larger values of $n$ where $\lambda_2 \neq \lambda_n$.

More generally every singular value can be characterized as both the solution to a maximization problem and the solution to a minimization problem; see e.g. [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/) for one way to do this (search for "variational").

Comment: Thanks! So, the result is more general, the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix also has its corresponding eigenvector that minimizes the quadratic form subject to the constraint that its norm is 1.  In particular, the unit-normed eigenvector that maxiimizes $x^\top A x$ subject to it being orthogonal to each of the $n-1$ eigenvectors (corresponding to the highest $n-1$ eigenvalues) also minimizes the quadratic norm $x^\top Ax$ among all unit-normed vectors $x$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, although note that once you've constrained as far as "unit vector orthogonal to the $n-1$ eigenvectors corresponding to the highest $n-1$ eigenvalues" you've already picked out a unique vector up to sign so the maximization problem is pretty degenerate at this point.